# GroupBY dates of a particular month

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

After joining two table on the basis of algo_id, i am trying to write a sqlalchemy code for getting the count of records which are there in a particular date:

```
algo_details columns : algo_id, algo_name,
algo_inference columns : algo_id, created_on,
```

format of created_on is '2022-02-24 15:07:14' (date time object)

i want to merge these two columns on the basis of algo_id and then want to get the count of records exist in a particular day of the month.

```
for example :
2022-02-24 15:07:14
2022-02-24 15:07:14
2022-02-24 15:07:14
2022-02-24 15:07:14
```

so for date feburary 2 the count will return as 4.

I tried doing this but i am not getting what i expected

```
query = db.query(algo_details.AlgoDetails.algo_name, algo_infrence.Details.status, func.count(algo_infrence.Details.created_on)).join(algo_details.AlgoDetails,
                                                                        
algo_infrence.Details.algo_id == algo_details.AlgoDetails.algo_id).filter(algo_details.AlgoDetails.algo_name==algo).group_by(algo_details.AlgoDetails.algo_name, 

func.day(algo_infrence.Details.created_on)).all()
```

Thanks

Comment: please update your sample input and output

Comment: use func.date if your intention is on calendar date inclusive of year